# Dual casting different spells

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't seem to find the information. Does getting the dual casting perk also work for dual casting different spells?

For example, if I have Frostbite in one hand, and Sparks in the other, will the combination creates something new, or will it just be better overall?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Dual Casting perks only apply to cases where you have the same spell equipped in both hands.

You can not combine spells to get interesting or useful 'combined effects'.

Answer (score 5):

The text of the dual-casting perk is:

"Dual casting **a** destruction **spell** overcharges the effects into an even more powerful version." (emphasis mine)

Since the hand animation changes when dual-casting the same spell and not different spells, and the perk description specifies singular, my guess is you cannot dual-cast different spells.

You can test this by using the impact perk, and seeing if you're still able to stagger opponents.

References:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Magic_Overview

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Perks